# Jquery load result into input text?

Tags: jquery, ajax, load

Hello how can i show load result in input field ?

```
<input type="text" placeholder="1" name="bah" style="width:70">
```

and i want to replace 5 to input value

```
result =    load( "tt.php", { "query":"bt","number":5} );
return $('input[name="bah"]').val(result);
```

Best regards

Comment: Please add some background-Information to your question

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/ try this

```
$.get( "tt.php",{param: 'test'},function( data ) {
  $('input[name="bah"]').val(data.number);
});

or 

$.ajax({
   type: 'get',
   url: 'tt.php',
   dataType: 'json',
   data: { param: 'test' },
   success: function(data) {
       $('input[name="bah"]').val(data.number);
   }
});
```

Comment: i need to post query and number

Comment: `{ "query":"bt","number":5}` are you trying to pass those params through ajax or you are expecting return value from ajax?

Comment: yep i want like this  return $('#person').val=load("tt.php", { "Name":name.value,"age":20,"date":date.value});